# Перенос последнего слова строки вместе с иконкой

Tags: веб-программирование, вёрстка, frontend

Есть строка.

Hello world ©

Копирайт идет в теге i сама строка в span все заключено в div

div

span - Hello world;

i - ©

Как при сжатии экрана сделать так чтобы на новую строку переносился копирайт вместе с последним словом строки. А не отдельно копирайт а потом слово world.

Comment: а Ваш код можно посмотреть?

Answer (score 0):

Просто оберните второе слово и иконку в обертку , пример по:
[ссылка на jsFF](https://jsfiddle.net/1cu0uagc/)

```
<span class="parent">
Hello
  <span>
    world
    <i>©</i>
  </span>
</span>

.parent {
  width:100px;
  display: block
}
.parent span {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Я не могу последнее слово оборачивать в span

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gmhshxxn/
Либо такой способ , но тогда не нужен тег <i>

Comment: Я не могу сделать span:after и задать ему contant потому что i у меня отдельный тег по которому всплывает тултип с объяснением

Comment: А потому нельзя обернуть последнее слово в span ?
можно еще сделать на js , но по моему это слишком.